# Nuget update on Unity throwing 500 with "Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.",

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

SO I had a perfectly working WebApi service with Unity. I decided to take Nuget package update which overwrote the UnityConfig.cs, However, i added my code back and it works all fine when I try to run it from VisualStudio. Problem is when i deploy the bin and try to run the api from IIS. I get a 500, with following exception :

> Exception.Source         = System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator
>   Exception.Message        = An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'StateController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

```
/// <summary>
/// Specifies the Unity configuration for the main container.
/// </summary>
public static class UnityConfig
{
    #region Unity Container
    private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container =
        new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            RegisterTypes(container);
            return container;
        });
    /// <summary>
    /// Configured Unity Container.
    /// </summary>
    public static IUnityContainer Container => container.Value;
    #endregion
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        string dbConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["abc"].ConnectionString;
        StateRepository stateRepository = new StateRepository(dbConnectionString);
        // Register a default (un-named) type mapping with a singleton lifetime
        container.RegisterInstance<IStateRepository>(stateRepository);
    }
}
```

Hers is my UnityWebApiActivator.cs

```
using System.Web.Http;
using Unity.AspNet.WebApi;
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(PowerManagementServices.UnityWebApiActivator), nameof(PowerManagementServices.UnityWebApiActivator.Start))]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof(PowerManagementServices.UnityWebApiActivator), nameof(PowerManagementServices.UnityWebApiActivator.Shutdown))]
namespace PowerManagementServices
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides the bootstrapping for integrating Unity with WebApi when it is hosted in ASP.NET.
    /// </summary>
    public static class UnityWebApiActivator
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Integrates Unity when the application starts.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            // Use UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver if you want to use
            // a new child container for each IHttpController resolution.
            // var resolver = new UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.Container);
            var resolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.Container);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Disposes the Unity container when the application is shut down.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Shutdown()
        {
            UnityConfig.Container.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

what is missing ? As I mentioned this service was working perfectly before I took the nuget update. Now it works from VS but not when deployed.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What does the constructor(s) look like for your StateController class?

Comment: private readonly IStateRepository stateRepository;

        public StateController(IStateRepository service)
        {
            stateRepository = service;
        }

Comment: I almost want to believe its not compiling properly.